# get the file extension during upload php

Tags: php

I'm trying to add the file extension to my file during upload. Since i'm finding it hard to do, i've already hard coded it to in small case `.jpeg` in my script. How do i get rid of the hard coded file extension and dynamically replace it with the original uploaded one because it could be `gif, pdf` etc.

```
<?php
$def_date=strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$rename = "gwcl_".rand(0,1000000000000).$def_date.".jpg";
$file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$folder="../complains_photos/";
$new_file_name = strtolower($rename);
move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$new_file_name);
echo $new_file_name
?>
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't trust file extensions as they can be mislabeled. It is always best to actually check the contents of the file to make sure it is what you are expecting with a function such as `mime-content-type()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` that you're using contains a temporary filename for the uploaded file.  But if you want the original filename, including extension, then use `$_FILES['file']['name']`.